Can the distance of any 2 points inside an isosceles triangle be more than the length of the equal sides?
There's an isosceles triangle. Two of its sides are equal to x and the remaining side is equal to y.
Can there be 2 points inside this triangle whose length is greater than or equal to x?
All answers here are only answering for the case where y>x. Please also answer for the x>=y case.
Source: I came up with this question on my own.

Pick

 any isosceles triangle where y > x, and take the two endpoints of the side with length y. If the points can't be on the boundary, any sufficiently close (i.e. within $\frac{y-x}{2}$ of the respective vertices) points will do.


What about the  x>y case ?

Such a triangle fits entirely within a circle of radius x centered at any vertex, so no distance greater than x are possible.

I know it seems obvious that in the x>y case, any line joining 2 points inside the triangle will be less than x. But I am unable to prove it. I have tried your circle method and other methods. Can you provide a formal proof or some link ?

For any two interior points (A and B), draw a line through them that intersects the triangle at C and D. Let E be a vertex such that CDE >= 90 degrees. Now AB <= CD, and CD <= CE (the hypotenuse of CDE), and CE <= x (because C, like the rest of the triangle, fits within a circle of radius x centered at E). So AB <= x.


 Yes, as long as y ≥ x. If this is true, then the points on each end of side y  are ≥ x apart.


You need >, not ≥.

I also thought this was the case, but the question clearly states "greater than or equal to".

What about the  x>y case ?
